# codeigniter 3.1.3, MSSQL, pdo: insert and select in one query

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, pdo

Look on my sample(i use codeigniter 3.1.3, mssql, php7)

```
    DECLARE @title int = 1;
    DECLARE 
    @temp  table (                                                         
    vname NVarChar(150), 
    vaddress NVarChar(150));


    insert into @temp (vname, vaddress) 
    VALUES   ('323435','1') 



SELECT * FROM @temp
```

This works well, insert wokr, but select dont work.
This is just sample, but i realy need to solve this issue.
I use code like:

```
$query = $this->db->query($sql);
$query->result()
```

What do i must do? ty.

Comment: Table names and column names need to be static, if the query is static. For dynamic table or column names, you should generate the full SQL dynamically, and use sp_executesql to execute it.

Comment: thank you for comment. I wrapped my query with exec like "exec( $sql )", but still nothing

Comment: Is the Select statement generating an error message or producing an empty result set?

Comment: Unfortunately, syntax error when i do select * from (exec($sql)), and empty result when only exec($sql).